# How do I keep a volume mounted when I boot up in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mount, unmount

How do I keep a volume mounted when I boot into Ubuntu 18.04

It disappears on every boot.

Thank you

Comment: I would add it to the `/etc/fstab` file (filesystem table) with a `auto` parameter (auto isn't needed for all fs types).  You didn't say what type of volume, so I can't be more specific

Comment: ext3/ext4  is the fileystem type

Comment: probably easiest, add something like `UUID=xxxxxxx   /mount-dir   ext4   defaults   0   0`  where UUID=the UUID for your partition, mount-dir is the directory you want it mounted to.  You can use your / or /home partition (assuming one of them is ext too) as your guide  (using `sudo blkid` to get the UUID for partition, *its more specific than /dev/sdxx*)

Answer (score 3):

Add an entry to your systems filesystem table (/etc/fstab) is the easiest method in my opinion.

For ext4 you can add the following

```
UUID=xxxxxxxx    /mount-dir    ext4    defaults    0    0
```

where the *xxxxxxxx* is replaced by your UUID (unique ID for the device/partition) and */mount-dir* is replaced by the directory you want it mounted to.  (space(s) or tabs can be used between parameters)

To find out the UUID, use `sudo blkid`